# The scope of if __name__ == __main__

Tags: python, scope

What is the scope of `if __name__ == __main__`? Is everything covered by this statement in global space ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is nothing special about `if __name__ == '__main__'` block whatsoever. That is to say, its scope is determined by the place it occurs. Since such blocks typically occur at top-level, their scope is global.

If this block were to occur in a function, which is perfectly legal, its scope would be local—except that `__name__` would still resolve to the global value defined in the module.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> if __name__ == '__main__':
...     x = 1
... print 'x' in globals()
True
```

**edit**:  user4815162342 makes the excellent point that this if-statement can be written in *any* scope.  It's most often written in the global scope.

Here it is inside a function:

```
>>> def foo():
...     if __name__ == '__main__':
...         bar = 1
... foo()
... print 'bar' in globals()
False
```

Comment: Somewhat confusingly, it's also in `locals()`: http://ideone.com/WbvTj. Presumably, at the module top level the global scope is the same as the local one.

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't have block-local scope, so any variables you use inside an `if` block will be added to the closest enclosing "real" scope. (For an `if..main` block, they'll usually be attributes of the module.)

Answer (score 2):

It is in the global scope as long as:

1. it is called in the global scope, i.e. not from within a function
2. it is in the code file that is being executed.

**To illustrate (2)**:

Suppose you're code is in `foo.py`, and in `bar.py`, you have the statement `from foo import *`. In this case, the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block in `foo.py` is not executed. This block is only executed when `foo.py` is run

Comment: Actually, `if __name__ == '__main__'` block is executed just fine, it's just that `__name__` happens not to be `__main__`, but `foo`. This setting of `__name__` is entirely orthogonal to variable scoping rules.

Comment: @user4815162342: You're right. I just wanted to make sure that the OP didn't import `foo` inside `bar` and wonder why variables in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` in `foo` didn't show up in `bar`'s global scope.